# how to show and show div using button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me how to show next `div` on button click `next` button .and show previous `div` on click of `previous` button .

https://jsbin.com/zeleloxifo/edit?html,css,js,output

I have `5` divs  .First time `first` div is display .When user click on `next` button it should show `second` div and hide `first` div .Then user click again it hide `second` div and show `third` div ..so on..`when user click on`previous`it show previous`div`

```
$(function(){

  $('#pre').click(function(){
    alert('pre');
    $('.imageBlock').hide();
     $('.imageBlock').show()
  })

  $('#next').click(function(){
    alert('next');
     $('.imageBlock').hide();
    $('.imageBlock').show()
  })

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a helping counter variable, which will hold an information what is the index of actually displayed image. Then, use `eq()` function to show the image of with current index.

```js
$(function() {

  var counter = 0;
  $('.currentPage').text(counter+1);
  $('#pre').prop('disabled', true);
  
  $('#next').click(function() {
    if (counter < 4) {
      counter++;
      $('.imageBlock').hide();
      $('.imageBlock').eq(counter).show();
    }
    $('.currentPage').text(counter+1);
  })
  $('#pre').click(function() {
    if (counter > 0) {
      counter--;
      $('.imageBlock').hide();
      $('.imageBlock').eq(counter).show();
    }
    $('.currentPage').text(counter+1);
  })
  
  $('#next, #pre').click(function() {
    if (counter == 0) {
      $('#pre').prop('disabled', true);
    } else if (counter == 4) {
      $('#next').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#pre').prop('disabled', false);
      $('#next').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  })

})
```

```css
div.imageBlock {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="slideno">
    <span class="currentPage">
    </span>/<span class="totalPage">5
    </span></div>
  <div class="imageBlock">1</div>
  <div class="imageBlock" style="display:none">2</div>
  <div class="imageBlock" style="display:none">3</div>
  <div class="imageBlock" style="display:none">4</div>
  <div class="imageBlock" style="display:none">5</div>
  <button id="next">next</button>
  <button id="pre">pre</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it is not updated above number "1/5" to "2/5"  like that `3/5`

Comment: can we hide `next` button when user on last div ..or can we hide `pre` button on first time

Comment: @user5711656 Is it fine? Remember to upvote/mark answer (: